# How do I get Word 2016 to render text the way that Word 2010 did?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2016

I originally had Microsoft Word 2010 installed on Windows 7.  I upgraded to Windows 10 and purchased Office 365.  So I have both Word 2010 and 2016 installed.  I have thousands of documents.  As I open different documents I am seeing many formatting inconsistencies.

I don't want to go through those thousands of document and check each one for compatibility errors.  Are there any options to maintain backward compatibility with how documents were rendered before?

Comment: If you expect us to help you could at least provide some examples ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: I will try to find some examples without a lot of custom fonts.  These are my wife's documents that she creates for teaching elementary and unfortunately she include a lot of custom fonts (some we have purchased).